# Ios Map annotation with button

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have such definition  of viewforAnnotation :

```
        - (MKPinAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id        <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    MKPinAnnotationView *view = nil;
    //MKPinAnnotationView *view=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"HotSpotsLoc"];

    if(annotation !=mapView.userLocation){
        view = (MKPinAnnotationView *)
        [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
        if(nil == view) {
            view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                     initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
        }



        UIButton *btnViewVenue = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        [btnViewVenue setTitle:@"Foo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView=btnViewVenue;
        view.enabled = YES;
        view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        view.canShowCallout = YES;
        view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
        //view.animatesDrop = YES;

    }       
    return view;
}
```

It generally works, adds a button and so on. But when I add :

```
 [btnViewVenue setTitle:@"Foo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

To set the title of button, the program does not work anymore, I can't add any annotations or anything, just have mapview. Can anyone tell me what is wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: You may also need to set the button's frame and titleColor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

`UIButton *btnViewVenue = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];`

to

`UIButton *btnViewVenue = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Comment: Ok, I understood it and it works, however it does not change label of button, there is no button visible or nothing like that ...

Comment: set button frame using [btnViewVenue setFrame:CGSizeMake(0,0,50,50)]; add button into view using [self.view addSubView btnViewVenue];